# Distribution of sine composed with a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Could you tell me if my calculations are correct?

We are given a random variable with the following discrete distribution $$P(X=n) = \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}, \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Find the distribution of $Y = \sin \frac{\pi X}{3}$.

So we need to find $$P(Y=n) = P(\sin \frac{\pi X}{3} = n) = P(X = \frac{3}{\pi} \arcsin n) = \frac{2^{\frac{3}{\pi} \arcsin n}}{3^{\frac{3}{\pi} \arcsin n+1}} $$

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off noticing that with $X$ confined to the non-negative integers, $Y$ can only take on the values $\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0$.  Thus, if we define $p_i \equiv P(X = i)$, we have

$$
P(Y = 0) = p_0 + p_3 + p_6 + \cdots = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{8}{27}} = \frac{9}{19}
$$
$$
P\left(Y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = (p_1 + p_2) + (p_7 + p_8) + \cdots
    = \frac{\frac{2}{9}+\frac{4}{27}}{1-\frac{64}{729}} = \frac{54}{133}
$$
$$
P\left(Y = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = (p_4 + p_5) + (p_{10} + p_{11}) + \cdots
    = \frac{8}{27} \cdot \frac{54}{133} = \frac{16}{133}
$$

ETA: Incidentally, $\mathbb{N}$ *usually* refers to the positive integers $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ (at least, that's how I've usually seen it).  However, there is some disagreement about that, and the distribution you give only makes sense for $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$—that is, the non-negative integers.